# Sails.JS + sails-auth + passport-openidconnect

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement passport-openidconnect into my Sails app. I've installed `sails-auth`, `passport`, `passport-local`, `passport-http`, and `passport-openidconnect`, all of which are required to start the sails app. [I copied the contents of this file](https://github.com/langateam/sails-auth/blob/master/config/passport.js) to get a passport config since the sails app was already started when I began implementing. This is my config file so far:

```
module.exports.passport = {

    openid_connect: {
        name: 'OpenID Connect',
        protocol: 'oauth2',
        strategy: require('passport-openidconnect').OAuth2Strategy,
        options: {
            clientID: '',
            clientSecret: ''
        }
    }

};
```

I based this off some of the default options that were in the `config/passport.js` file mentioned above.

I've searched for setup examples for the OpenID Connect, but haven't been able to find anything so far. Has anyone implemented this in their own project and could give me some pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented passport in sails, with passport-local, passport for Google/FB/Twitter, but without sails-auth !

I don't know passport-openID but this should be nearly the same.

First you need to add passport middleware like [this](https://github.com/Embraser01/IUT-PTUT/blob/master/config/http.js#L26) in your config/http.js

Then you have to create the different strategy in [config/passport.js](https://github.com/Embraser01/IUT-PTUT#configuration) (exemple with FacebookStrategy, it should

```
var passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
    , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy

var verifyExtHandler = function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    checkAuthExt(profile, done);
};

var verifyHandler = function (mail, password, done) {

    checkAuth(mail, password, done);

};

// Passport session setup.
// To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
// serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session. Typically,
// this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
// the user by ID when deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    user.password = null;
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

// Use the LocalStrategy within Passport.
// Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
// credentials (in this case, a username and password), and invoke a callback
// with a user object.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'mail',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, verifyHandler));

// Remplacer les 'XXXXX' par vos clés et 'yourhost.com' par votre nom de domaine
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: "XXXXXX",
    clientSecret: "XXXXXX",
    callbackURL: "http://yourhost.com/auth/facebook"
}, verifyExtHandler));
```

And you need to configure your routes (config/routes.js) :

```
'/auth/facebook': 'AuthController.facebook',
'/auth/facebook/callback': 'AuthController.facebook'
```

Then in your controller :

```
facebook: function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login'
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.serverError();
                return;
            }

            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res);
}
```

Hope that helps !